# Flutter TextField Widget errorText not passing value

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am creating a Textfield Widget that should allow em to re-use the code fro several input fields.  Everything seems to work except that I am experiencing strange behaviour of the errorText property when using the widget.  When using the same code directly the erorText updates properly but from within the Widget it doesnt.

A print in the onChanged event shows that the values in the onChanged event are properly recorded but dont get passed to the errorText (checking value with etTest function)

```
Widget inputRfField(String type, TextEditingController _controller, String suffix) {
String errorMessage;
bool _errorTextValid ;
return Expanded(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      onChanged: (_value) {

        double contValue = double.parse(_value);
        setState(() {
          if (type == 'Theta') {
            contValue <= 90 && contValue >= 0 ? rxThetaValid = false : rxThetaValid = true;
            rxThetaValid == true ? errorMessage = 'Theta 0-90 ' : errorMessage = null;
            _errorTextValid = rxThetaValid;
          } else if (type == 'Phi') {
            contValue <= 360 && contValue >= 0 ? rxPhiValid = false : rxPhiValid = true;
            rxPhiValid == true ? errorMessage = 'Phi 0-360 ' : errorMessage = null;
            _errorTextValid = rxPhiValid;
          } else if (type == 'Lpa') {
            contValue <= 90 && contValue >= 0 ? rxLpaValid = false : rxLpaValid = true;
            rxLpaValid == true ? errorMessage = 'ERR: Lpa 0-90 ' : errorMessage = null;
            _errorTextValid = rxLpaValid;
          }
          print('errorTextValid: '+ _errorTextValid.toString());
          print('controllerValue: ' + contValue.toString());
        });

      },
      keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: false),
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
      textAlign: TextAlign.end,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open, color: Colors.grey),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: type.toUpperCase(),
        suffixText: suffix,
        errorText: etTest(_errorTextValid) == true ? errorMessage : null,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

The console returns

I/flutter (31158): errorTextValid: true

I/flutter (31158): controllerValue: 99.0

I/flutter (31158): errorTextValid at errorText: null

I/flutter (31158): errorTextValid: false

I/flutter (31158): controllerValue: 9.0

I/flutter (31158): errorTextValid at errorText: null

I/flutter (31158): errorTextValid: true

I/flutter (31158): controllerValue: 96.0

I/flutter (31158): errorTextValid at errorText: null

Somehow errorTextValid is not passed on.  Yet when not running this from a widget

```
child: TextFormField(
controller: rxFrequencyController,
    onChanged: (frequencyController) {
        double rxFreq = double.parse(frequencyController);
        rxFreq < 11200 || rxFreq > 12750 ? rxValid = true : rxValid = false;
        setState(() {});
    },
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: false),
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber),
textAlign: TextAlign.end,
decoration: new InputDecoration(
    //prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open, color: Colors.grey),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: "RX frequency",
    suffixText: "MHz",
    errorText: rxValid == true ? 'Frequency out of range: 11200-12750 MHz' : null,
    ),
),
```

it works fine.

What am I missing ???

Comment: You're missing a call to setState(), the widget is stateless so it won't update until a call to ```setState``` is made. When you're doing it from outside widget you're calling the ```setState``` that's why it's working.

Comment: Thanks danypata, but I would think I am calling setstate in the widget just after double contValue = double.parse(_value);

Comment: Hi danypata, this helped me on the way ... I looked further and found the solution by making teh widget a stateful widget.